# vbScript automatic file download by extension

Tags: file, vbscript, download, file-extension

I have found this usefull vbscript [on the web](http://vbscriptautomation.net/73/download-files-using-vbscript) to automate file download.

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation)

'create xmlhttp object
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

'get the remote file
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, false

'send the request
objXMLHTTP.send()

'wait until the data has downloaded successfully
do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 :  wscript.sleep(1000) :  loop

'if the data has downloaded sucessfully
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then

        'create binary stream object
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open

        'adTypeBinary
    objADOStream.Type = 1
    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody

        'Set the stream position to the start
    objADOStream.Position = 0    

        'create file system object to allow the script to check for an existing file
        Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        'check if the file exists, if it exists then delete it
    If objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation

        'destroy file system object
    Set objFSO = Nothing

        'save the ado stream to a file
    objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation

        'close the ado stream
    objADOStream.Close

    'destroy the ado stream object
    Set objADOStream = Nothing

'end object downloaded successfully
End if

'destroy xml http object
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

End function

download "http://remote-location-of-file", "C:\name-of-file-and-extension"
```

Is there a way to force it to parse the url and for example download *.exe file in some web location? like this:

```
URL:  http://examplesite.com/files/

file0001.exe
```

because I have a URL which has a file which name changes during time. It has .exe extension.

I have both http and ftp protocols enabled over it and ftp has no authentication (free).

Answer (score 0):

That would only be possible if on that site filebrowsing would be enabled and that is rarely the case. You will need some URL where the name of the files are listed to parse the filenames. You would better use a tool like wget http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/ which has such options. Also vbscript is not a good choice for such operations, if you start from scratch you would be better of with eg Ruby.

If you publish the URL in question maybe i can help you further.